# Google Drive Api in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm doing project in MVC C#, and working Google Drive Api.

I was on the site [daimto.com](http://daimto.com) and I took the samples and put in my MVC application.
In site https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ and create two credencias:

[image: Licenças do Google APIs]

The license for name **Cliente Padrão** works locally, the license **Site SESMT** should run on the server, but to access the page that has the release access, the site is thinking and thinking goes nowhere, it seems caught . My license to use on the server is as follows:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

I've looked examples on the internet, but it's all for local application and nothing for Web application. I'm thinking that something is missing.

#### Question

My page is thinking and thinking goes nowhere and does not show the authorization screen. Funny that in my local environment works

### My Code

#### Autorização

```
public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
{
    string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,  // view and manage your files and documents
                                        DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,  // view and manage its own configuration data
                                        DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly,   // view your drive apps
                                        DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,   // view and manage files created by this app
                                        DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,   // view metadata for files
                                        DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,   // view files and documents on your drive
                                        DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts };  // modify your app scripts



    var folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/GoogleDriveApi");
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                    , scopes
                                                                                    , userName
                                                                                    , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                    , new FileDataStore(folder)).Result;

    DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "site-sesmt"                
    });

    return service;
}
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string CLIENT_ID = "***.apps.googleusercontent.com";            
    string CLIENT_SECRET = "***";            
    DriveService service = GoogleApi.AuthenticateOauth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "portalsesmt");

    return View();         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem a few weeks back when I was doing the exact same thing. If you are using Oauth 2.0, you have to enable the Google+ API in Google API Console->Dashboard->Enable API->Google+ API.

At least this solved the problem for me for some reason. I think google changed their APIs or something. Try that out and let me know if it worked.

Comment: For me not working; Your project is MVC C#? If yes, please sending part of project with Google Drive and Google Authentication. Url for test: http://flex.tiedt.com.br/Blog/Inserir

Comment: I was using MVC.NET C# v3 and OAuth 2.0 . The class that handles the authentication: http://pastebin.com/f7mpZjBL.

Comment: I'm pretty lost. Could make a small complete example of authentication? The community itself will it.

Comment: This is the example in C# provided by Google itself - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/dotnet.
I know it's not in a MVC architecture but at least the connection and configuration are present in Step 3.